# Ray + cross_val_score

Tags: python, ray

I am learning [ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray) at the moment and I saw that there is some integration with scikit-learn. I was wondering if anybody could tell me if there is a ray implementation of [cross_val_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html)?
I know that there is hyperparamter tuning in ray, so my gut feeling is that maybe there is also a function similar or at least close to cross_val_score.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, [tune-sklearn](https://github.com/ray-project/tune-sklearn) allows you to do a grid search and also implements cross validation. However, I agree that this is a bit roundabout -- could you file a feature request on `tune-sklearn`?